# javascript+jquery monkeypatching / replace / override a class method

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding, monkeypatching

```
$.fn.uWorklet = function() {
  var worklet = this;
  var plugin = {
    pushContent: function(target, data) {
    . . .
    }
  }
  return plugin;
}
```

In the above, I want to replace method pushContent with my own. Is this possible to do, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You want to mess around with private scope? There are ways of doing this but, don't tell anyone you learned this from me:

```
> var foo = function() { var x = 1; return x; };
undefined
> foo()
1
> foo = new Function(foo.toString().replace(/^function\s()[^{]+{|}$/gi, '') \
       .replace(/var x = 1/, 'var x = 2'))
function anonymous() {
  var x = 2; return x; 
}
> foo()
2
```

Joking aside, there has to be a better solution to your problem: if this is your code then make it more modular, if it's a library, then fork the code & fix it.

Comment: (I know this isn't actually getting at the scope; just replacing the definition. You used to be able to do this with `eval` but, most browsers have patched that.)

Comment: +1 for last sentence, but don't even show this snippet to anyone =)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just replace the entire `uWorklet` method? If you have the code, you can just copy it, replace the `pushContent` method and replace the whole thing.

Otherwise, I don't think you can, at least not with the code you've shown thus far. Maybe add some example of how you'd use the `uWorklet` method, since it looks like it returns an object, and maybe you can replace the method in that object....